# solve possible Session error using Xero php API

Tags: php, xero-api, xero

I am using https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2-app and following a change from Cpanel to StackCP by my host I am getting the following warnings and the file no longer creates the invoices, it did work perfectly last month and if I run the authorization page it works fine as well.

I assume it is a problem creating a session.

Output: (I have edited the paths as I wasn't sure if it could allow someone access)

> Warning: Undefined array key "oauth2" in /home/sites/31a/9/xxxxxxxx/xero/storage.php on line 15

> Curl error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "access_token" in /home/sites/31a/9/xero_monthly_inv_lt.php on line 54

> Warning: Undefined array key "id_token" in /home/sites/31a/9/xero_monthly_inv_lt.php on line 55

> Warning: Undefined array key "refresh_token" in /home/sites/31a/9/xero_monthly_inv_lt.php on line 56

> Warning: Undefined array key "expires_in" in /home/sites/31a/9/xero_monthly_inv_lt.php on line 57

Comment: if you haven't solved this yet, feel free to reach out - contact details in my profile